# Xamarin.Forms, как передать json в php?

Tags: php, c#, json, post

Доброго времени суток. Помогите разобраться в том как передать json из Xamarin.forms в php?

Я последовал примеру кода который указан по этой ссылке: http://metanit.com/sharp/xamarin/10.3.php

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.RequestUri = newUri("http://path.ru/mobile_create_PDF_entrante.php");
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.Content = content;
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

И написал json данные в классе, которые отправляю в php:

```
string json = @"{ FIO: '" + Form_Entrant.Entry_FIO.Text + "' " + ", Residence_Address: '" + Form_Entrant.Entry_Residence_Address.Text + "' " + ", Passport_Series: '" + Form_Entrant.Entry_Passport_Series.Text + "' " + ", Passport_Number: '" + Form_Entrant.Entry_Passport_Number.Text + "' " + ", Place_Residence: '" + Form_Entrant.Entry_Place_Residence.Text + "' " + ", Data_Give_Out: '" + Form_Entrant.Entry_Data_Give_Out.Text + "' " + ", Photo_Signature: '" + Photo_Signature_Base64 + "' " + ", Now_Date: '" + Now_Date.Text + "' }";
```

Но не имею представление как получить зашифрованный json в php.

Comment: В php есть специальный супер глобальный массив `$_POST`. Все, что вы отправляете, хранится в нем. А вообще, почему бы не использовать `using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {....}`

Comment: WebClient - я не использую так как не знаю какую точно добавлять библиотеку в NuGet.

Можно уточнить следующее в php  с помощью `$_POST` я должен получить переменную json, а не FIO, Residence_Address и т.д.? 
Так как если я правильно понимаю нужно сделать еще `json_decode($json)` ,чтобы в дальнейшем использовать объекты FIO, Residence_Address и т.д.

Comment: @And `WebClient` для Xamarin скорее всего не подойдет, т.к. он устаревший, на смену ему пришел `HttpClient`

Comment: @D.Dante, по этому я и говорю, чтобы вы смогли увидеть, сделайте `var_dump($_POST)` или `print_r($_POST)` и дополните свой вопрос, что получили, а я составлю правильный ответ. @Bulson, понял. ну http роднее.

Comment: Я сделал вывод `$_POST` в файл .txt и получил пустой POST. Не совсем понимаю, в чем может быть причина получение пустого POST?